# React-tables How do you get the table column name?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I created a react-table and I am using an onclick but I am trying to access the header name.

```
getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
  return {
   onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
     console.log("It was in this column:", column);
     console.log("It was in this row:", rowInfo);

     if (handleOriginal) {
       handleOriginal();
     }
    }
  };
}}
```

The column log comes back undefined and inside the rowInfo I can't find the name of the column header. Is there another way to go about this?

EDIT: I figured out how to access the header name by changing the getTrProps to getTdProps but the only thing is my header for each column is a function. When I take the function away and just do

```
Header: "Name"
```

it works but I have

```
Header: () => {
 //code in here
}
```

how would I access it if it's inside of a function?

Thank you everybody for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `Header` with function as:

```
if(typeof column.Header === "function"){
  console.log(column.Header())
}
```

You will see the details under `column.Header().props`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a `TanStack` thing, but for me

```
cell.column.id
```

worked to get the value of the header for that column/cell.